# PXE install on several laptops keeps failing

Tags: 14.04, pxe

Having issues with PXE install for Ubuntu 14.04 on multiple laptops.

I am running tftpd32 on a windows 10 machine. I have the PXE files to boot the laptops and the laptops will boot over PXE. The issue comes up while downloading the Ubuntu Mirror. It will work until I hit 18% and then it fails with error downloading file. I have tried multiple mirrors and even downloaded the mirror to my working machine and then sharing it to the laptops. With the mirror local on my machine it will not even begin to download to the laptops. I have 13 laptops to install ubuntu on and they do not have cd drives and will not boot from SD or USB.